# OpenGL 4 Alpha Blending without Using Texture

Tags: alphablending, opengl-4

I have a list of triangles and some of them are overlapped each other. I would like to use alpha channel to show that darker space means there are a lot of overlaps. But, although I append alpha channel, it did not show the effect. Below is part of my code.

I have initialized OpenGL with

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0); 
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

**vertices** is a vector. I put these values: (x, y, R, G, B, A) one by one by using "push_back" function.

```
float* vertices_ptr = &vertices[0];
GLuint vao, vbo;

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

// Transfer data from CPU to GPU
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size()*sizeof(GLfloat), vertices_ptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2/* x y */, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(0 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4/* R G B A */, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 6*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size()/6);
```

Does anyone have face same problem? Thank you so much for helping me figure it out!